# How to clear the value of search input field in another page

Tags: reactjs

I am having a search bar in one of my ReactJS page.

```
<div className="input-group col-md-12">
     <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="searchApplicationInput" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.handleChange} />
         <span className="input-group-btn">
             <button className="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">
               <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
             </button>
         </span>
 </div>
```

This page is called in another ReactJS page. I am calling this div on click of a modal popup. The problem is when I am clicking model popup and typing any string to do a search, it's getting persisted. When i am closing modal popup and opening it again, the same search string is there. How can I clear the value of search input field in the page where this is being called. If modal open and close function is written in same page where i wrote html of search, then it can be cleared easily on opening of model by writing:

`this.refs.searchApplicationInput.value = "";`

How can i clear it in another page. Please give me suggestions. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you passing `searchApplicationInput` ref as a prop?

Comment: No, the search logic is written in the same page where it's html is defined. I have called this complete page on a modal in another page.

Comment: Does console.log prints the value of `this.refs.searchApplicationInput.value`?

Comment: NO, it doesn't.

Comment: So, You have to pass the `ref` or another prop that will hold the value.

Comment: It can print value only in the page where it's HTML is written, Not in another page where the page is called.

Comment: Can u please give me a little demo of it.

Comment: The problem is if I am passing any empty value in prop, and assigning it to the value attribute in HTML, then it is always empty, even if I will write any string in search box, it won't show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206165/discussion-between-cas-and-muhammad-zeeshan).